# nextjs RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
import React from "react";
import "../assets/style/global.scss";
import cookies from "next-cookies";
import client from "../lib/api/client";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  const appProps = await MyApp.getInitialProps(appContext);
  const { ctx } = appContext;
  const allCookies = cookies(ctx);
  const token = allCookies["accessToken"];
  if (token !== undefined) {
    client.defaults.headers.Authorization = token;
  }

  return { ...appProps };
};

export default MyApp;
```

When logging in, we try to put the access token in a cookie and put the cookie value in the header in every api request. But I get this error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

You get that error because you're generating an infinite loop by calling `MyApp.getInitialProps(appContext)` inside `MyApp.getInitialProps`.

Simply replace that line with an `App.getInitialProps` call instead.

```js
// ...
import App from 'next/app'

// ...

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
    const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
    // ...

    return { ...appProps };
};
```

Answer (score 5):

This once happened to me where I was accidentaly importing the component into itself. Inside **Layout.js** had `import RightPanel from "./"` instead of `import RightPanel from "../pages/rightPanel"`.

Answer (score 2):

One fine day, this error did come knocking out of nowhere on a nextjs project I was working.

```
...
maximum call stack size exceeded
event - build page: /next/dist/pages/_error
wait  - compiling...
error - static/chunks/pages/_app.js
...
```

A good old

```
rm -rf node_modules
yarn
```

did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error , using nodejs version 16,,
but when I downgraded it to version 14 , the dissappeared..

to downgrade  you can do

```
npm install -g n
```

then run:

```
n 14.17.4
```

after this delete you **node_modules** folder ,
and restart the application again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had a wrong `import` name for a component because I changed it's name and forgot to change the `import` statements in `pages`. Fixed the issue by changing the component `import` name.

Answer (score 0):

this error occur when exceed returing --(return {
massage: "Page created",
status: true,
payload: payload,
};)-- data size from server action so reduce returnning data then this will work properly